# Find user ID from comment on a post in Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/comment

In this, there is no field to find the user who is made the comment. However, this is publicily available on facebook but graph API doesn't allow it.

For example, if get the comment id 124125235235_124242353254, there what can I do to find the user who commented it?

graph.facebook.com/5550296508_10157585378836509?fields=comments&access_token=XXX

Comment: The `from` field of the comments should give you the user id; but it looks like you need a page access token for the request now.

Comment: It says , "Field is empty or disallowed by access token". How do I get page access token?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from Graph API v2.11, you need a page access token to get the (scoped) user_id from any endpoint (comments and reactions, for a start).

(See [v2.11 90 Days Breaking Changes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90-pages))

> /page/* — User information will **not be included** in GET responses for
>   any objects owned by (on) a Page unless the request is made with a
>   Page access token. This affects all nodes and edges that return data
>   for objects owned by a Page.

This is already happening to API calls made with `2.11` prefix. E.G.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/5550296508_10157585378836509?fields=comments&access_token=XXX
```

You can still go to the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and taylor your request to be made against an older endpoint or build your own request as

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/5550296508_10157585378836509?fields=comments&access_token=XXX
```

However, IIRC, 90 Days Breaking Changes means that in 90 days this policy will affect all API versions, so older apps will no longer return the user ids.

**How do you get a page token?**

In the Graph API Explorer you can generate tokens **for the pages you have access to**.

And **to get access to a page**, you need to be authorized by a page admin. He can authorize you by going to his page, then click on 
 **settings -> page roles**.

[image]

I guess you need the least privilege to actually get scoped user_ids.

Comment: is there an alternative way to do it? something works around this change?

Comment: not that I know of. Perhaps they forgot to modify a given endpoint, but if that was the case, they will patch it as soon as they notice. So, basically, you need to either have a role in that page or make someone who has a role login into your Facebook App and have facebook to approve permission `pages_show_list` and I guess also  `read_insights`

Comment: I'm following FB documentation(developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v8.0/comment) and using Graph API v8.0. I have page access token with required permissions. I am able to get the list of comments but it doesn't show anything for the from field. Any suggestion on this. Thanks